# JSON file with value session?

Tags: php, json, if-statement

For my Bootstrap page, I have à json file who set his display conditions. I would like hide a colomn if not a admin.

Is it possible to use an if statement inside a JSON file with value session? (In an external Json file)

Like this:

```
[
  {"if":"$_SESSION['droit']==2","name":"last_connect","title":"Last connect","breakpoints":"xs sm md","visible":true,"filterable":false, "style":{"maxWidth":120,"whiteSpace":"nowrap","text-align":"center"}}
]
```

Comment: No, it is not. And instead you should describe __real problem__ that you want to solve with this.

Comment: For my Bootstrap page, I have à json file who set his display conditions. I would like hide a colomn if not a admin.

Comment: And how's being admin/not admin connected with json?

Comment: My question was: After login, If I'm a admin ($_SESSION['droit']==2), I can show all column of a page or hide some of them.

Comment: Are you really proposing that you store your serverside logic on the client? And you think this is a good idea because....? It is not supported by JSON, and while it would be easy to build the capability in Javascript, it would be a very silly thing to do.

Comment: So, the best solution would be to choose the json file based on the value of the session?